# Question count/average questions per day bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I was looking at the site stats today for Lifehacks and I was confused about the question count. It says we have 492 questions, we have been in beta for 79 days (78 according to Area 51), and we have and average of 4.8 questions per day (4.6 according to Area 51). I didn't think these numbers were right, so I went on my trusty calculator. Well, `492/78 = 6.23` and `4.8 * 79 = 379.2`. Now, I'm pretty sure 379 does not equal 492. I thought that maybe closed questions don't count, but there are [57 closed questions](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes), `492-57 = 435` and 379 does not equal 435. So what is the explanation for this? Is it a bug? Or does the system only take the last few weeks as data?

Comment: I believe the Area 51 calculation is a 7-day average, not a lifetime average.

Comment: I wonder if deleted questions are included...